# Try running ‘Pull’ first to integrate your changes VS Code GitHub error

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

When changes are pushed from local to remote server error "Try running ‘Pull’ first to integrate your changes"

Answer (score 1):

use git pull first to merge remote changes

1. press control+ ~
2. type the following command

```bash
git pull
```

or just use vscode

[image]

PS:
you really need to learn the basics of git

[getting started about git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control)

Answer (score 0):

In your Visual Studio Code, go to the three
dots here:

[image: dots]

Hover over the "push, pull" option and click on the "pull from" option. Then select your remote repository and then branch.
Now push the changes again.